# Can't set qtcreator settings by modify QtCreator.ini in ~/.configure/QtProject

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I was trying to find where QtCreator save it's `settings`, for setting some `initializing options` in qtcreator so that other team members don't need set by themselves. After i google, i found qtcreator save it's settings in `~/.configure/QtProject/QtCreator.ini`, so i try to modify this file manually. But i found this didn't work soon, because when i open qtcreator, this file will be initialized by qtcreator and the modification would `wipe off`. Is there any way i can set qtcreator settings `outside`(like `Build%Run` settings, some `CMake variable` settings like `CMake_CXX_COMPILER` and so on )?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a set of *CMake* settings available to your team members, perhaps you may want to consider providing a toolchain file with your project instead of Qt Creator settings. A toolchain file can define various CMake variables and is a particularly good way of specifying what compilers to use (it is the canonical way of setting up a cross-compiling build, for example). A toolchain file can even be re-used for multiple projects if required and it doesn't rely on developers all using the same IDE tool or lock them into a particular CMake generator type. To use a toolchain file with a project, developers only have to add an option like `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/your/toolchainfile.cmake` to their CMake command line. This can be done within Qt Creator when first loading the project via its CMakeLists.txt file or it can be done as a first step outside of Qt Creator if the developer prefers. In short, the toolchain file approach is more flexible and is a well-defined way of setting up a known, easily reusable compiler environment. The [toolchains section](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) of the CMake documentation may be worth a read to get a bit of background on this approach, but remember you don't have to be cross-compiling to use a toolchain file. It's valid and useful even when not cross-compiling.